# Choosing a framework for a portfolio website

Tags: frontend, web-testing

I am currently trying to code an art/code portfolio for myself. Ideally, I want a new page to be generate for each file or directory in a certain directory of images, where I can display the image and a little blurb about each piece or project. What would be the best framework to choose to accomplish this?

I currently accomplish this using a static site, but this requires the manual entry and editing of each page.